# Converting fromMap millisecondsSinceEpoch to DateTime in dart

Tags: json, datetime, angular, firebase, dart

I'm storing a DateTime as millisecondsSinceEpoch in firebase json, and then when calling fromMap I want to convert from millisecondsSinceEpoch.

Which is the most appropriate way to do this other than my current?

`new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['created_at'])`

**Message Class**

```
class Message {
  final String name;
  final String text;
  String photoURL;
  String imageURL;
  DateTime created_at;

  Message(this.name, this.created_at, [this.text, String photoURL, this.imageURL]) {
    this.photoURL = photoURL ??
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/"
  }


  Message.fromMap(Map map) :
        this(map['name'], new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['created_at']),  map['text'], map['photoURL'], map['imageURL']);


  Map toMap() =>
      {
        "name": name,
        "created_at": created_at.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
        "text": text,
        "photoURL": photoURL,
        "imageURL": imageURL
      };
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the way you're using right now?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good to me.

The only potential problem I can see with your current code is that it creates the `DateTime` object in the local time zone. If you want it as a time stamp, you may want to always use UTC times, so maybe you want:

```dart
new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['created_at'], isUtc: true)
```

Then again, if the date is displayed to the user, using local time could very well be the right thing to do.

Another potential concern is that the map may contain a string instead of a number, but your example here has a number, so that's probably not an issue. Just make sure you know what the JSON contains.

(But to nitpick, the `created_at` member would normally be written as `createdAt` in Dart).